# Why can't refer interface variables by using super keyword

Tags: java, oop

I'm new to java and as per my knowledge, normally, we use the `super` and `this` keywords to refer to the superclass properties. As well as we cannot use `this` and `super` keywords inside the static context(static methods). but I have a question. I used an anonymous class to use an interface as follows. I tried to refer the `number` variable (which located in interface) from inside the anonymous class. But even it is not a static context, I cannot refer number by using `super` keyword. What is the problem?. my code like below.

```
    interface Age{
       public static final int number =25;
       public abstract int getAge();
    }

    public class Main {
      public static void main(String[] args) {
        Age age = new Age(){
            public int getAge(){
              int number = super.number;//compile error
              //why cannot use super keyword in here to refer number variable
              return number;
            }
        };
        age.getAge();
      }
   }
```

Comment: I'd say that's because you can implement multiple interfaces from a single class, so the `super` keyword would be ambiguous as to which interface you were referring to

Comment: You don't need the local variable. Just `return number;` Don't write redudant code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `super` keyword refers to the parent *class*, not to any interface. In the code you've provided, `Age` is an interface. You would see the same behavior regardless of whether you're looking at an anonymous class or a named class.

If you're wondering *why* the language designers decided not to allow `super` to refer to an interface, Aggragoth commented on this: a class can implement multiple interfaces, so if they each had a member named `number` it would be impossible for the compiler to be sure which interface's `number` you are trying to refer to with `super.number`.

Comment: In addition, all fields in interfaces are `public static final` by defaul (no need to declare in explicitly) making them a constant fields, not a instance members.

Answer (score 0):

`int number = super.number;` 
In Interface every variable declared is final, i.e its value can't be changed. Moreover, the keyword `super` is used to get `public, protected or default variables` of the parent class, not the interface. Due to these reasons, the compiler throws an error here.

As StriplingWarrior and Aggragoth, had already said a class can implement multiple interfaces, so if they each had a member named `number` it would be impossible for the compiler to be sure which interface's number you are trying to refer to with `super.number`.